# How to convert DbSet to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to create a value converter which will convert `DbSet<MyEntity>` to `ObservableCollection<MyEntity>` so that I can bind it easily to a combobox in WPF XAML.  I want it to work across all types.

I have tried this so far.

```
class DbSetToObservableCollectionConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            DbSet<T> d = (DbSet<T>)value; //How do I know what to put in place of T
            return new ObservableCollection<T>(d);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This does not work as T is not really a type.
Can somebody help me what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this in a converter. Do it in the ViewModel. That way, your ViewModel will have a strongly typed reference to the `DbSet<T>` (not just an `object`) and will know what type `T` is.

Comment: uhhmm ok. Do you know if there is a way to tell EntityFramework to generate ObservableCollection of Entities instead of DbSet of Entities?

Comment: @AnkurSharma That shouldn't be a responsibility of the ORM. I don't know if there is a way for that but I would not do it anyways. Create an intermediate service layer between the ORM and the ViewModels if you don't want to place this logic in the ViewModels themselves.

Comment: I see the logic of MVVM but in the application I am creating there are many entities and there are going to be many instances of the entities  and i feel I am going to have to do a lot of work if I have to type all of these again and again in ViewModel.

Comment: maybe your view model can have a method like public List<T> GetEntities<T>() { return context.Set<T>().ToList() }

Comment: So we can use the ViewModel, but it can't be as simple as `ctype(DbSet<T>, ObservableCollection<T>)`, can it?

Answer (score 2):

Having:

```
 DbSet<Thread> Threads;
```

Use:

```
ObservableCollection<Thread> Threads;            

 using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            Threads =new ObservableCollection<Thread>(db.Threads);
        }
```